# Automatically control parquet file size

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a (scala/spark) DataFrame `df` that I would like to save to parquet with roughly 128MB per parquet file. Based on the schema, I roughly estimated the size, in MB, of one line.
My strategy is to repartition the dataframe, with a value that generates "oversized" partitions. Then I leverage the option `maxRecordsPerFile` to get my wanted parquet file size:

```
val countLines          = df.count
val estimatedSize       = countLines * 250 / (1024 * 1024) // one line is around 250 Bytes
val repartitionEstimate = (estimatedSize / 512).toInt + 1 //I "under" repartition my dataframe so I get roughly 512MB per partition
val maxRecordsPerFile   = ((128 / 250.0) * 1024 * 1024).toLong //I save, hoping to have only 128MB-heavy parquet files

df.repartition(repartitionEstimate).write
  .option("maxRecordsPerFile", maxRecordsPerFile).partitionBy(
    "year",
    "month",
    "day",
    "hour"
  ).parquet(outputPath)
```

When I did this, I got in each of my folders parquet files of about 128MB but some of them were very tiny, like 10MB. How could I solve this? I would rather have a 133MB file than one 128MB and one 5MB file! So I would like my solution to be a little bit more flexible. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The reason I am not directly repartitioning based on the 128MB size is that, while it is working fine if I have a single folder, it seems to "break" with hourly folders: in one I had mostly 80MB files, in another mostly 40MB files...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `coalesce()` over `repartition()` in this case.

repartition is great when you want to write files in even sized chunks where as with coalesce your file size in disk won't  of even size but you will not have any tiny files.

for instance, if your file size is 331MB then with

- `repartition(2)` : you will end up with two files of 165.5 MB or so.
- `coalesce(2)` :    you might end up with a 163.5 MB file and a 167.5 MB or so.

Note : you can't really infer the size in disk before writing the data from memory to disk, due to spark data compression & encoding hence this is file size of 331 MB is hypothetical.